# Cassandra and CCM on Ubuntu, network loopback alias

Tags: networking, cassandra

Hi When I try to start CCM I get this error:

```
ccmlib.common.UnavailableSocketError: Inet address 127.0.0.1:9042 is not available: [Errno 98] Address already in use; a cluster may already be running or you may need to add the loopback alias
```

I know I need to add Loopback alais, however this command just work on OSX:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2 up
```

and I added 3 loop back on Ubuntu by this in interface:

```
auto lo lo:0 lo:1 lo:2
iface lo inet loopback

iface lo:0 inet static
        address 127.0.0.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 127.0.0.0

iface lo:1 inet static
        address 127.0.0.3
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 127.0.0.0

iface lo:2 inet static
        address 127.0.0.4
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 127.0.0.0
```

I still get same error after running `ccm start`!

Answer (score 0):

there are two solutions to your problem:

1. you have another window in you terminal running a Cassandra instance (./cassandra) you should first close this window and re-run ccm start.
2. Your should use aliases this issue has already been addressed [here](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm/issues/87).

Regards,
Magaly

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ifconfig lo:0 127.0.0.2 netmask 255.0.0.0 up
sudo ifconfig lo:1 127.0.0.3 netmask 255.0.0.0 up
sudo ifconfig lo:2 127.0.0.4 netmask 255.0.0.0 up
```